# Circular Contour Integration .

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Doing some revision for an upcoming exam I have stumbled across the following problem:

Evaluate the integral $\int_{C}\log(z)$ where $C=C(2,1)$ the positively oriented circular contour, centre 2, radius 1.

My workings so far: $C=2+e^{it}$. Therefore $\gamma=2+e^{it} \implies \gamma'=ie^{it}$.

Therefore our integral becomes $\int_{0}^{2\pi}log(2+e^{it}).(ie^{it})dt$ 
via the path integral formula.
However this looks wrong and i have a feeling i may have to use the fundamental theorem of contour integration, however I may also be wrong on that! Any help please ?

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the region the contour encloses, so since the contour is closed, the integral is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the principle branch of the complex logorithm which takes away $(-\infty,0]$, then your logorithm is analytic in the region of integration so by Cauchy's theorem it's 0.

On the other hand, your logorithm is lower-case "l", so if you're using a different branch the answer will not necessarily be 0.

Comment: I think you may be on the right lines, for a 6 mark exam question how would i go about getting the marks ?

Comment: @user112365: like I said, this question is ambiguous without a properly assigned branch. If this is from a textbook, check the assumptions in the relevant section.